# Angular ng2-flatpickr clear date button

Tags: angular, datepicker

how can I clear date from ng2-flatpickr

I have this code:

```
<ng2-flatpickr [config]="dateOptions" placeholder="" name="DateValue" #DateValue
   [(ngModel)]="dateValue">
</ng2-flatpickr>
<button (click)="clearDate()">clear</button>
```

In ts:

```
clearDate() {
   dateValue = null;
}
```

ex:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-flatpickr-clear-date-kxw3qc?file=src/app/app.component.html

but not worked. Any help please

Comment: add a stackblitz